# New command for printbibliography forwarding arguments

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I had something like

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,resetnumbers=true,subtype={somelable},   title ={Nice Titlel}]
```

then I noticed links were not working and had to

```
\phantomsection\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,resetnumbers=true,subtype={somelable},   title ={Nice Title}]
```

That's even bigger.

May I have a shorter command for this like?

```
\myprntbib[subtype={somelable},title ={Nice Title}]
```

Comment: Not really the point: But do you *absolutely* need the `\phantomsection`? It seems to me that should usually not be necessary. In any case it would probably better added in the heading definition directly.

Comment: Without the `\phantomsection` links from Contents don't point to the right place. Perhaps there is another solution instead of using `\phantomsection`?

Comment: Mhhh, OK. I can't really say more without a real example that shows which document class you use and reproduces the botched link. If you like you can ask a new question, but if the `\phantomsection` works for you, you might not feel an urgent need to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `\printbibliography` the following should work

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, defernumbers, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\myprntbib}[1][]{%
  \phantomsection
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, resetnumbers=true, #1]}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
  entrysubtype = {somelable},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\myprntbib[subtype={somelable}, title ={Nice Title}]
\end{document}
```